# In IE 9 how do I move the favourites bar back to the left-hand side like it was in IE 8?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I just upgraded to IE 9 and I find the default placement of the favourites column to the right side super-nutty.  Is there any way to place it back to the left?  I tried dragging but nothing came of it.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Favorites pane, then click this button:

[image]

This will pin the Favorites pane to the left side of the IE window. It'll only stay there until you close it, though, and in its unpinned state it'll always appear on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Click the star to open favorites, then click the last button to move it to the left, I think it's called Dock

Comment: Which last button?  The "settings" button is my button beside the star!

Comment: I meant on the Favourites window. Indrek posted what one I wanted to, I posted my original answer from my phone